# Which sentences are correct?

Tags: grammar

1. One of the best times of my life
2. One of the best time of my life
3. One of the best times I've had
4. One of the best time I've had

Comment: What research have you done? What sentences do you think are incorrect and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 3 are correct. There are several "best times", and this is one of them. If this was the (singular) best time, there would be no need for "one of".